# text recongnition & events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do different things depending of what the user is typing.
I'm actually able to detect what an user is typing but I somehow can't do anything with it.
I would like to check if `letters === "a"` and do a simple console.log, but it doesn't work.

Also, I'm pretty new to jquery and it's great to learn it, so if you see anything that I could improve in my code, do not hesitate!

```js
function individuaLetters(e){
    e.each(function(){
       var letters = $(this).html().split();

       console.log(letters)
       if (letters === "a") {
          console.log("nailed it")
       };
    })
}
var text = $('div').find('.indiv');

individuaLetters(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class="indiv">"a"</span>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split creates an array, so letters will never be a string after you split it. Plus you have quotes to take care of.

I got rid of your split and used regular expressions to remove all non letters and then lower case the string.

```js
function individuaLetters(e){
    e.each(function(){
      var letters = $(this).html().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,"").toLowerCase();
      if (letters === "a") {
         console.log("nailed it")
      };
    })
  }
      var text = $('.indiv');
      individuaLetters(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class="indiv">"a"</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it's working!
had to change `/[^a-zA-Z]/g,""` to `/[^a-zA-Z]/g," "` so it keeps the spaces between the words when you have sentences